# Which version of node.js is running on Windows Azure Web Sites?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Which version of node.js is actually running on Windows Azure Web Sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out to be, at the moment of writing: **v0.6.20**.

Quickly found out via the following script:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'})
    res.end('Version - ' + process.version);
}).listen(process.env.port || 1337)
```

To follow and try it yourself [follow these steps](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/FindOutWhichVersionOfNodejsCurrentlyRunsOnWindowsAzureWebSites.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

There are many versions of node preinstalled on the Windows Azure Web Sites servers and you can choose which one gets used by specifying your minimum required version in your package.json file.  Instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/specifying-a-node-version/).

The versions available change on a regular basis, but to give you a sense, the currently available versions (as of November 1, 2013) is: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21.

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find the currently-supported Node versions?

Answer (score 3):

I found this: 
http://hardcoded.se/2015/01/07/node-js-version-on-azure-websites/

In the KUDU environment of your app (accessible through the url deletemesoon.scm.azurewebsites.net if your website has the url deletemesoon.azurewebsites.net) hit runtime versions and you will receive a JSON representation of available versions. 
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

By default 0.6.20

**BUT** you can set your own version:

1. Upload (ftp) node executable (not the installer!) to **bin** folder in your **wwwroot** or wherever you please. i.e. get it from here: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node.exe
2. Add

   ```
   nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\node.exe"
   ```

to **iisnode.yml** (must be located where your **server.js** is)

[source: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/specifying-a-node-version/ ]